# thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0) when button is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

when you press a button in my app you should be transferred to another viewcontroller and a label in the second viewcontroller should be set to a new text, but it only works to be transferred to the second view controller not when i add the code so that the labels text should change. then this error pops up: thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

And yes both viewcontrollers has the same view controllers set to them.

if you know the answer please leave a comment on this post :)

```
@IBAction func done(sender: UIButton) {                
 let countInMeters = count * 6
    metersTest.text = "apr \(countInMeters) meters"
}
```

Comment: what is `count`? is `metersTest` certainly non-`nil`?

Comment: another possibility is that the ibaction has gone "rouge", i.e., your button has been disconnected to this action. Try to re-initialize these connections from scratch (ctrl-drag).

Comment: You might want to review this before you ask your next question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

From the wording of your question it seems you are trying to modify a control on a target view controller within the code of a control belonging to the original view controller.

That would never work because, when you are in the original view controller's button code.  Your metersTest.text is probably a member of the original controller and is probably not connected to anything.  It certainly can't be connected to the target controller which is an entirely different object.

If you need to transfer data between view controller, you could intercept the transition between them at a point when you have access to both the original and the target.    For example, if you override func prepareForSegue(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender sender: AnyObject?) in your original view controller, you can assign data to the target controller at that point.